# Why RecyclerView onBindViewHolder called just once?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Have a strange bug in my code. I use Recycler View (used in the past without any problem). I created test ArrayList for showing it in Recycler but I get the only first row in RecyclerView and after it, the app stops (not crashes) like ArrayList was finished.

My Main Code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_tab, container, false);

    Activity activity = getActivity();

    //TODO: For testing ONLY
    ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        orders.add(new Order(i, i, i));
    }

    // Initialising Orders Recycler View.
    OrderAdapter orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(activity, orders);
    RecyclerView recyclerViewOrders = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recylerViewAllDiners);
    recyclerViewOrders.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
    recyclerViewOrders.setAdapter(orderAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

Adapter:

```
package com.slavafleer.tipcalculator;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Order Adapter for Order Recycler View
 */
public class OrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Order> orders;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Order> orders) {

        this.context = context;
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    @Override
    public OrderHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_order, parent, false);

        return new OrderHolder(view);
    }

    // TODO: why it has been done just once ?
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(OrderHolder holder, int position) {

        Order order = orders.get(position);

        holder.bindOrder(order);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orders.size();
    }
}
```

Holder:

```
package com.slavafleer.tipcalculator;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Order Holder for Order Recycler View
 */
public class OrderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView textViewOrderId;
    private TextView textViewDinerId;
    private TextView textViewPrice;

    public OrderHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewOrderId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOrderId);
        textViewDinerId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDinerId);
        textViewPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
    }

    // Bind Data Object to the Views.
    public void bindOrder(Order order) {

        textViewOrderId.setText(order.getOrderId() + "");
        textViewDinerId.setText(order.getDinerId() + "");
        textViewPrice.setText(order.getPrice() + "");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At first, Febi Mathew, thank you for trying to help me with this.

I found how to fix it.

My original line in Gradle was

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```

after I did sample just for Recycler and it was the same, I tried an older version

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

And it worked perfectly. So I suppose it is not my bug =). If you know how to report for this bug, you welcome to do it.

Update:
 What was wrong is I didn't set layout-height for my item as wrap content. And from reason that I don't understand on old version it did not matter but on a new one it just takes all my screen and I didn't think to try to slide it down.

Comment: I don't know if it is important, but I am working on beta 6 version of Android Studio 2.0

Comment: Might be an issue with instant run. Have you tried a clean install of a clean build with 23.2 library?

Comment: WarrenFaith, not so sure what did you mean (Have you tried a clean install of a clean build with 23.2 library? ) But this is not over =) On my simple test RecyclerView it worked as I said before, but on my project it has the old effect. I think I would try to uninstall the beta and try same on the stable release of Android Studio.

Comment: I would suggest to remove your app from emulator/device, make a "build -> clean" and try again to run and install it with the 23.2.0 library. The instant run feature just "injects" new code and still seems to have some issues, so I wonder if the code your AS injects might be already buggy

Comment: I feel so stupid =) What was wrong is I didn't set layout-height for my item as wrap content. And from reason that I don't understand on old version it did not matter but on a new one it just takes all my screen and I didn't think to try to slide it down. Really stupid situation but I happy It is in the past. Just took time for reinstalling studio =). Thanks again for trying to help me.

Comment: Please update your answer with the layout-height findings you mentioned in the comment

Answer (score 7):

Check it out if the outermost element of the item layout height IS NOT set to "match_parent" value, but is set to "wrap_content" or some Ndp value. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"  // Just like this!
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

I have also encountered the same problem because the wrong height parameter is set.

It should be **wrap_content**, but I set the layout-height = match_parent.

So the first list item will occupy all the space in the list view, so it only displays a list item.

Comment: .it helped me a lot .i was digging why onBindViewHolder called only first item not all item even i added log .finally your answer helped me .thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_order, parent, false);

    return new OrderHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Order order = orders.get(position);

    OrderHolder orderHolder = (OrderHolder)holder;
    orderHolder.bindOrder(order);
}
```

Comment: onBindViewHolder is @Override, so I can't change its arguments.

Comment: Replace your "extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderHolder>" with "extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>"

Comment: Why should he replace that when is OrderHolder extends from RecyclerView.ViewHolder? There is no need for that in this case

Answer (score 0):

My Previous commit Recyclerview support version : 24.2.1

Later I updated build.gradle by adding following:

```
> configurations.all {
   >     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
   >         def requested = details.requested
   >         if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
   >             if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
   >                 details.useVersion '25.3.0'
   >             }
   >         }
   >     } }
```

So after this all support versions have been upgraded to 25.3.0 except for "multidex". This means recyclerview version also upgraded.

Here is the issue, after this running a build My recyclerview onbindviewholder method is not called.

Any how I found this cause after commenting above code and running, able to use my recyclerview

Hope this may useful for someone.

Regards
Vinod